# OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken() is not working in Outlook Chrome Incognito and Safari

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to build an Outlook add-in that uses SSO for user authentication. Which will run on all supported platforms such as Mac Outlook native client, all browsers. But `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()` is returning an error 13006 in Chrome Incognito window and Safari, as cross-site tracking (Third party cookies) is disabled. [Troubleshoot error messages for single sign-on (SSO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins) this document does not mention anything regarding third party cookies.

It works as expected on other clients.
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: See if this article helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/itp-and-third-party-cookies

Comment: Thank you @RickKirkham, But this document suggests implementing an Oauth flow for my add-in in a pop-up. I wanted to get the bootstrap token silently so that I can use the `onBehalfOf` flow on the server. SSO provided by office.js should work right?

Comment: I've learned internally at Microsoft that this is a known bug: "ITP and Chrome Incognito will block third-party cookies, which invalidate our silent auth flow implementation. ... SSO [cannot be used] when third-party cookies aren't available. ... Today the best workaround is to use interactive flow for third-party cookie blocking scenario."